# Select photos by multiple tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three MySQL tables - photos, tags and tagsphotos - and m:n relationship between photos and tags.

```
Photos:     id | filename | ...
Tags:       id | name
Tagsphotos: photo | tag
```

I want to select all photos with this condition:

```
(tagged as "dirty" AND tagged as "road") AND (tagged as "light.front" OR tagged as "light.side") AND (tagged as "perspective.two-point")
```

...which means that I want to find all pictures with dirty road, in two-point perspective and either with side or front light.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going to have to join the tags table to the photos table four times... pretty ugly.

```
SELECT Photos.*
FROM
  Photos
  JOIN (
    Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
  ) t1 ON (t1.photo = Photos.id)
  JOIN (
    Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
  ) t2 ON (t2.photo = Photos.id)
  JOIN (
    Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
  ) t3 ON (t3.photo = Photos.id)
  JOIN (
    Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
  ) t4 ON (t4.photo = Photos.id)
WHERE
      (t1.name = 'dirty' AND t2.name = 'road')
  AND (t3.name = 'light.front' OR t3.name = 'light.side')
  AND (t4.name = 'perspective.two-point')
```

Subqueries would probably be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM Photos
WHERE
  Photos.id IN (
    SELECT Tagspohotos.photo
    FROM Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
    WHERE Tags.name = 'dirty'
  )
  AND Photos.id IN (
    SELECT Tagspohotos.photo
    FROM Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
    WHERE Tags.name = 'road'
  )
  AND Photos.id IN (
    SELECT Tagspohotos.photo
    FROM Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
    WHERE Tags.name = 'light.front' OR Tags.name = 'light.side'
  )
  AND Photos.id IN (
    SELECT Tagspohotos.photo
    FROM Tagsphotos JOIN Tags ON (Tags.id = Tagsphotos.tag)
    WHERE Tags.name = 'perspective.two-point'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I didn't realise you were using MySQL - updated answer given below.

Assuming that each tag can only be specified once for each photo (i.e. a photo cannot be tagged as 'dirty' multiple times):

```
SELECT      P.id,
            P.[filename]
FROM        Photos P
INNER JOIN  Tagsphotos TP ON TP.photo = P.id
INNER JOIN  Tags T ON TP.tag = T.id
INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT  'dirty' name,
                10 [weight]
        UNION
        SELECT  'road' name,
                10 [weight]
        UNION
        SELECT  'perspective.two-point' name,
                10 [weight]
        UNION
        SELECT  'light.front' name,
                1 [weight]
        UNION
        SELECT  'light.side' name,
                1 [weight]
) R ON T.name = R.name
GROUP BY    P.id,
            P.[filename]
HAVING  SUM(R.[weight]) >= 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming photo and tag columns are the ids:

```
select p.* from Photos p, Tags t, Tagsphotos tp
where p.id = tp.photo and t.id = tp.tag
and t.tagged in ("dirty", "road", "perspective.two-point", "light.front")
group by p.photo
having count(distinct t.tagged) = 4

UNION

select p.* from Photos p, Tags t, Tagsphotos tp
where p.id = tp.photo and t.id = tp.tag
and t.tagged in ("dirty", "road", "perspective.two-point", "light.side")
group by p.photo
having count(distinct t.tagged) = 4
```

Comment: `WHERE t.tagged = x AND t.tagged = y`? How will that ever return a results if `x<>y`?

Comment: And now, what do you think? :P